# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 6): Firebase Authentication not finding

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

So this is my first time using stack overflow so I'm sorry if this looks bad! I'm having trouble setting up my React Native App Firebase Authentication. I want my user to login first then have it go to the next screen. My problem is I'm having trouble with Firebase not being able to authenticate. I have been looking at the google firebase docs and other stack questions but none have helped me.

Here my code:

```
//React and CSS
import * as React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput} from 'react-native';
import LoginButton from '../components/LoginButton';
import ForgotPassButton from '../components/ForgotPassButton';

//Help screen after login
import Help from '../pages/Help';

// Login Function
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

class LoginForum extends React.Component {
async _logMeIn() {
    console.log('hi');
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword('Janunda@ivytech.edu', 'Pa$$w0rd')
      .then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Help'))
      .catch(error => this.setState({errorMessage: error.message}));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.backgroundColor}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.userInput}
          placeholder="Email"
          placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.8)"
          returnKeyType="next"
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.userInput}
          placeholder="Password"
          placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.8)"
        />
        <LoginButton
          buttonName="Login"
          customTouchableStyle={{
            width: '75%',
            height: '50%',
          }}
          customViewStyle={{backgroundColor: '#FFAB40'}}
          onPress={this._logMeIn}
        />
        <ForgotPassButton
          buttonName="Forgot Password"
          customTouchableStyle={{
            width: '10%',
            height: '40%',
          }}
          customViewStyle={{backgroundColor: '#EB3461'}}
          // onPress={userLogin.handleLogin}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  userInput: {
    width: '75%',
    padding: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    height: 50,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    marginTop: 58,
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    flexGrow: 1,
    fontSize: 25,
  },
  loginButton: {
    height: 70,
    paddingVertical: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,0,1.8)',
  },
  loginText: {
    fontWeight: '700',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  forgotPassword: {
    fontWeight: '700',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    padding: 30,
    fontSize: 20,
  },
});

export default LoginForum;
```

Error:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 6):
TypeError: _auth.default.auth is not a function. (In '_auth.default.auth()', '_auth.default.auth' is undefined)
_logMeIn$@http://localhost:8081/forum/LoginForum.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=true&runModule=false&shallow=true:65:35
tryCatch@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:30556:23
invoke@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:30732:32
tryCatch@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:30556:23
invoke@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:30632:30
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:30662:19
tryCallTwo@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:3329:9
doResolve@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:3493:25
Promise@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:3352:14
callInvokeWithMethodAndArg@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:30661:33
enqueue@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:30666:157
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:30683:69
_logMeIn@http://localhost:8081/forum/LoginForum.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=true&runModule=false&shallow=true:59:42
onPress@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:57595:34
_performTransitionSideEffects@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:57151:22
_receiveSignal@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:57089:45
onResponderRelease@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:57007:34
invokeGuardedCallbackImpl@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:12754:21
invokeGuardedCallback@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:12848:42
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:12852:36
executeDispatch@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:12957:48
executeDispatchesInOrder@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:12977:26
executeDispatchesAndRelease@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:13078:35
forEach@[native code]
forEachAccumulated@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:13068:22
runEventsInBatch@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:13102:27
runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:13186:25
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:14226:42
batchedUpdates$1@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:26457:20
batchedUpdates@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:14164:36
_receiveRootNodeIDEvent@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:14225:23
receiveTouches@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:14255:34
__callFunction@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2755:49
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2477:31
__guard@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2709:15
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2476:21
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]
```

Comment: Did you initialize configs with firebase?

Comment: Yes, I initialize the config

Comment: Are you ready to publish your app or do you just want to test it works? If just to test it check your firebase database rules that they allow you to read and write to your database: `{ "rules": { ".read": true, ".write": true }}`